# Auto-play video/audio blocked in Safari, Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio

This problem has been around for many years but the apparent fixes on here and other sites are not helping.

I want to either:

- Autoplay a video with sound in all browsers
- Autoplay audio in all browsers
- Autoplay video with no sound and the same time as autoplaying audio
  from a separate file

This is the code being used:

```
<body>
    <video muted preload autoplay loop playsinline poster="/lib/vid/home.gif">
        <source src="/lib/vid/home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
<script>
    
    var music = new Howl({
    src: ['/lib/audio/home.mp3'],
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true
  });
  
  music.play();

</script>
```

As you see I am using the recommended library Howl which is supposed to help with auto-playing audio, but audio is being blocked in all the browsers until there is a user interaction.

I have gotten round the video problem by making a GIF placeholder which thankfully works ok for this video so the main priority is autoplaying the audio.

A number of sites I have checked offering solution with demos don't seem to work anymore, so maybe autoplay is just not possible anymore?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) you'll only get autoplay of audio if the user has permitted in their browser settings.

Comment: Correct. This is a purposeful browser restriction to stop sites from being spammy with noise and being a general nuisance -- advertisements blaring etc. So you can't do it on all browsers, especially mobile. I encourage you to pause and understand why web users didn't want this in the first place.

Comment: I didn't realise there had been a vote.